# Get array sum and return the value through a method in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays

I have this code sample with a method which returns the sum of array values. But instead of the sum, I'm getting 0.

This is my code sample

```
class Calculation {

    int answer;

    public int SumOfArrays(int data[], int size) {
        answer = 0;
        for (int i = data[0]; i < size; i++) {
            answer += data[i];
            //System.out.println(data[i]);
        }        
        return answer;
    }

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calculation cal = new Calculation();
        int data[]={10,20};
        System.out.println(cal.SumOfArrays(data, 2));            
    }
}
```

**can anyone tell me what;s wrong with my code?**

Comment: Why should i be initialized to data[0]? i is supposed to be the index in the array. Not a value of the array. And why do you pass size as argument? The size of the array is data.length. No need for an additional parameter. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: `size` is the array size. without using `data.length` I need to set array size manually as a parameter in the method.

Comment: `System.out.println(Arrays.stream(data).sum());` Don't reinvent the wheel. And if you must reinvent the wheel, use a `for-each` loop.

Comment: No, you don't. If I give you my car, I don't need to give you a paper with the color of my car. You can know its color by just looking at the car. If you receive an array, you can know its length by looking at the value of its length attribute. Passing an additional parameter is redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop doesn't run at all - the condition `data[0] < size` is `false`, so the initial value of `answer = 0` is returned.

To make it work, change the statement to `(int i = 0; i < size; i++)`. Also, `size` might be replaced with `data.length`.

Comment: @user8794865, if you set `size` manually, you need to validate it to make sure it is within the bounds `[0, data.length)`

Answer (score 1):

This is your code with minor corrections. Try it.

```
class Calculation {

    public int SumOfArrays(int data[]) {
        int answer = 0; // this is just better
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            answer += data[i];
        }        
        return answer;
    }

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calculation cal = new Calculation();
        int data[]={10,20};
        System.out.println(cal.SumOfArrays(data));            
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to input array size manually. How can I do that without omitting the `size` parameter?

Comment: @user8794865 why do you need this? if you want to calculate only sum of the first few elements then you need it, otherwise array has  `length` that returns its size

Comment: if you still need the second parameter, just add it as it was `SumOfArrays(int data[], int size)` and also add it here `for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)` and in Main `cal.SumOfArrays(data, 2)` - as it was before

Answer (score 1):

The counter `i` for the for loop is incorrectly initialized. You have initialized it to the value of first element in the array instead of 0. Initialize it to 0 as shown below:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        answer += data[i];
        //System.out.println(data[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from your loop
`for(int i = data[0]; i < size; i++)` 
the variable `i` is equals to the first element in the `data array` which means that is greater then the `size` variable ..so the loop will not begin at all 
to fix the problem change your loop to this

```
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        answer += data[i];
        //System.out.println(data[i]);
    }
```